# Cognos Report on Bluemix error, Rave not supported?

Tags: cognos, ibm-cloud

I am using Reporting service to display a report I created. I have the following error:

[image]

The data and the connection shouldn't be a problem...the report has RAVE visualization engine....might be this the problem? Is it supported?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some more info about what the contents of the report are or any other error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of reports containing RAVE charts is not currently supported. To have RAVE Viz. available, the visualizations used must be hosted on Bluemix and present within the service for common consumption.  In this Beta, we don't yet have a means to host the visualizations from AnalyticZone at this time. It is something we have received feedback on and are looking into for future releases.
Thank you for your interest in using the service - this is valuable feedback!

Anthony Schofield - IBM Platform Product Manager - Business Analytics